# In black ops 1 how to unlock all classifed weapons and camo?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I've played Call of Duty: Black Ops (the first version) a lot but I haven't found out how to get every weapon and the gold camo. I'm rank 33 and I heard that to get this weapon, I need to be a certain rank. Does anyone know what rank this is?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you clarify your question? Perhaps a specific weapon you are trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

### Classified Weapons

The final weapon in each Category (the "Classified" weapon) is unlocked by having all of the other weapons of that category available for use in loadouts (unlocked AND BOUGHT). For each category, the minimum level this is possible is as follows:

- Assault Rifle (G11): Level 44
- SMG (Kiparis): Level 41
- Shotgun (HS-10): Level 24
- LMG (Stoner63): Level 21
- Sniper Rifle (PSG1): Level 27
- Pistol (CZ75): Level 18

### Golden Camos

Golden Camos are unlocked for purchase on all applicable weapons at Prestige level 14. Each level of Prestige requires a grand total of 1,202,800 XP to get (this is the exact amount of XP required to get from level 1 to level 50).